# Auth state change listener being fired twice?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

When my page loads I need to know whether the user is logged in and perform different tasks based on that. The first thing I do is check if the they are logged in, but for some reason the `if` statement to check that is being validated twice. Here is my code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    FIRAuth.auth()?.addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
        if let user = user {
           print("User is logged in")
        }
```

"User is logged in" gets printed out twice to the console when the page loads instead of just once. Am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: One of those might be when it refreshed the token.

Comment: Ok, should I just set a flag variable after the first validation so I don't perform all the functions twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i faced same problem. and it is not for logged in . it can be faced flowing option 
 https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener

- Right after the listener has been registered
- When a user is signed in
- When the current user is signed out
- When the current user changes
- When there is a change in the current user's token

so just crate a flag then check that one . or check response `nil` or not

Try this way :

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    FIRAuth.auth()?.addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
        if let user = user {
            if user != nil {
               print("User is logged in")
           }
        }
```

Note : try to use both  `flag` and check `user =! nil`